# How Many Diphthongs Are There In English?

Tags: pronunciation, american-english, vowels, diphthongs

I was talking to a person who said that there were only two. I think she said that the "ou" in house is one of the two.

I told her that the way the letter "i" is pronounced is a diphthong, and she said it wasn't. She said it was just one vowel, "i" and that that was that.

She said she studied phonics and was writing her thesis (on child development, I think) on this kind of stuff. She said her book said there were only two diphthongs and that I was wrong.

So, how many are there? I told her I think there are probably more like ten.
I thought of six immediately, but she said they weren't diphthongs because her book didn't say they were.

1. "i" in time
2. "i" in bite
3. "o" in bone
4. "a" in bane
5. "oi" in boink
6. "ou" in house

Comment: Every accent of English has its own diphthongs (and i as in the 'time' is a diphthong in every accent I have ever heard).

Comment: "phonics" != "phonetics". Don't worry about it too much...

Comment: @JAM: Southern AmE characteristically monophthongizes /ai/ to /a/: "I like to iron" is standardly /ai laik t aijrn/ but in SoAmE is /a lak tarn/ (more or less).

Comment: @tchrist, I've never seen a reputable phonetician argue that "the phonemic diphthong set is pretty fixed." What exactly does it mean, set? The number of diphthongs? Contrastive pairs? Set where? By whom?

Comment: @NeilCoffey I told her I studied phonetics, and she said, "phonics, phonetics, same thing. What's the difference?" I guess you just can't ever be right with some people.

Comment: The first question you have to ask her is "are diphthongs *written* with two vowels, or *spoken* with two vowels?" If she can't give a straight answer to this question, ask to see the book she's referencing. If she says "what's the difference?", offer one of yours

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Certainly the *i* in words like *bite* and *fright* represents an `/aɪ/` diphthong.

**Phonemically**, I come up with these:

1. `/aɪ/` as in *price, my, high, flight, mice*
2. `/aʊ/` as in *mouth, now, trout*
3. `/eɪ/` as in *face, date, day, they, grey, pain, reign*
4. `/ɔɪ/` as in *choice, boy, hoist*
5. `/oʊ/` as in *goat, toe, tow, soul, rope, cold*
6. `/juː/` as in *cute, few, dew, ewe*
7. `/jə/` as in *onion, union, million, scallion, scullion*

Most examples are taken from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_chart_for_English_dialects). What those all actually work out to **phonetically** varies a great deal across dialects and speakers.  For example, [many and perhaps even most North American speakers raise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_raising) the `/aɪ/` in *tight* to `[ʌɪ]`, but not the one in *died*. You may wish to check out [SoundComparisons.COM](http://www.soundcomparisons.com/), where you can both see and hear the phonetic transcriptions for speakers of many, many different dialects, including words like [*four*](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/ByWord/Word_027_four.htm), [*hear*](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/ByWord/Word_034_hear.htm), [*eight*](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/ByWord/Word_019_eight.htm), [*cold*](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/ByWord/Word_010_cold.htm), [*cow*](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/ByWord/Word_012_cow.htm), [*fight*](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/ByWord/Word_023_fight.htm).

You could also analyse words like *way, yay, wow, yow* as triphthongs if you really wanted to, although we don’t tend to do so in English. Instead they tend to have an initial `/w/` or `/j/` followed by a diphthong in normal notation. <sup><sub>(In Spanish though they’d be considered triphthongs, as in *cambiáis*, which has just two syllables, *cam-* and *-biáis*.)</sub></sup>

Non-rhotic speakers claim to have others, but I have trouble thinking of those as diphthongs myself. I always analyse diphthongs as having a principal vowel to act as the syllabic nucleus and then a glide either before or after it. If the glide comes before the main vowel, as in `/jə/, /juː/`, it is a rising diphthong, and if the glide comes after the main vowel, as in `/aɪ/, /eɪ/, /aʊ/, /oʊ/, /ɔɪ/`, it is a falling diphthong. (Some people consider only the falling ones “real” diphthongs. I’m not sure why, since *million* has only two syllables for me, not three.)

I know of no diphthongs in English that have no glide in them, although whether you write your glides with `/j/` and `/w/` or as semivowels makes no great difference.  This leads to alternate transcriptions, as in `/eɪ/` for `/ej/`, and `/aʊ/` for `/aw/`.

If there is no glide, I don’t count it as a diphthong.  That means that  I don’t read `/ʊə/` as a single syllable. Rather, it has two syllables, as in the programming language named *Lua* `/ˈlʊːə/`. I guess I might write that `/ˈlʊː.ə/` if I thought people might misunderstand me. And no, it is not homophonic with monosyllabic *lure* `/ˈl(j)ʊːɹ/`.

Non-rhotic speakers sometimes analyse words with  words with ‹r› in them as diphthongs, where they substitute `/ə/` for `/ɹ/`, but since that’s not a glide, it’s not going to make a new diphthong in my book; it might make a new syllable, though.  Even though I say *fire* `/faɪɹ/`, I realize that they say `/faɪ.ə/`.  For me that would then rhyme with the disyllabic *maya* `/ˈmɑjɑ/, /ˈmaɪ.ə/`, although it becomes challenging to assign the `/j/` to one syllable or the other. I don’t see people writing *fire* `/ˈfajəɹ/`, but at least then it would seem like two syllables. But you end up reassigning the glide and changing the word from having an `/aɪ/` diphthong in the first syllable to having a `/jə/` syllable in the second.

For the record, here’s how I see the following *r*-bearing words:

- *bearer* `/ˈbe(ɪ)ɹəɹ/`
- *tourer* `/ˈtʰʊɹəɹ/`
- *nearer* `/ˈniːɹəɹ/`
- *curer* `/ˈkʰjʊɹəɹ/`
- *layer* `/ˈleɪ.əɹ/`, `/ˈle.jəɹ/`
- *lair* `/leɪɹ/`
- *fiery* `/ˈfaɪɹi/` <sup><sub>(two syllables)</sub></sup>, `/ˈfa.jəɹi/` <sup><sub>(three syllables)</sub></sup>
- *fairy* `/ˈfeɪɹi/`
- *Faëry* `/ˈfe.jəɹi/` <sup><sub>(for trisyllabic rhymes in poetry)</sub></sup>
- *more* `/mo(ʊ)ɹ/`, `/mɔɹ/`
- *mower* `/ˈmoʊ.əɹ/`, `/ˈmowəɹ/`

In that analysis, ‹r› is never part of a diphthong because `/ɹ/` is not a glide, and if you write it as a schwa, you’ve likely introduced another second syllable. Non-rhotic AmE speakers (such as those from the South) always sound like they have have more syllables in their words to those of us from the North. The joke is there is no such thing as a one-syllable word in “Suthun”. For example, *more* is one syllable in the North’s `/mo(ʊ)ɹ/`, but two in the South’s `/ˈmowə/`.

Lastly, I realize that you can write ‹-er› as `/ɚ/` or `/ɹ̩/`, as in *murder* written as either `/ˈmərdər/` or `/ˈmɝdɚ/`.  The problem is that we have only two rhotacized IPA symbols, stressed `/ɝ/` and unstressed `/ɚ/`; for anything else that you want rhotacized, you have to use U+02DE `MODIFIER LETTER RHOTIC HOOK`, which doesn’t look so hot in most fonts, and doesn’t count as a combining character.

Comment: I believe the exact number varies by region.  Certainly, speakers in my region pronounce "goat" and "soul" differently; so I know I have at least seven.

Comment: and speaking of my region, The New Zealand Oxford Dictionary lists ten; and this doesn't include either of the two in _union_ (which I pronounce /ju:njən/).  Its list is _day_, _my_, _boy_, _no_, _how_, _near_, _hair_, _tour_, _fire_, _sour_.

Comment: Out of interest, how would you analyse "bearer", "tourer" and "nearer" for your speech?

Comment: @NeilCoffey I'm not sure whether you're asking me or tchrist.  But I'm fairly sure I have a diphthong in "nearer", but not in "bearer" or "tourer".  FWIW, I characterise my own accent as "Urban North Island New Zealand".

Comment: I was actually referring to the assertion in tchrist's answer that diphthongs in these words are restricted to non-rhotic speakers.

Comment: @NeilCoffey I didn't think it was clear from tchrist's answer which words he/she thought had diphthongs only for non-rhotic speakers.  But "nearer" seems to me like an excellent candidate for one that might have a single vowel for rhotic speakers and a diphthong for others.

Comment: @Neil: Why are you asking about *bearer*, *tourer* and *nearer,* and not *bear*, *tour*, and *near?* I would think rhotic Americans would be considerably more likely to have diphthongs in the last three.

Comment: @NeilCoffey Good morning.  For me, *bearer* `/ˈbeɪɹəɹ/`, *tourer* `/ˈtʰʊɹəɹ/`, *nearer* `/ˈniːɹəɹ/`, *fiery* `/ˈfaɪɹi/`, *curer* `/ˈkʰjʊɹəɹ/`. See why I don’t call those special diphthongs just because they should have ‹r›? It’s because I don’t think of `/ɹ/` as a vowel nor a glide like `/j/` or `/w/`, so it doesn’t participate in diphthongs; `/ə/` is also no glide, so *maya* `/ˈmɑjɑ/`, `/ˈmaɪə/` is disyllabic not a triphthong. I realize you can write ‹-er› as `/ɚ/`, `/ɹ̩/`, as in *murder* `/ˈmərdər/`, `/ˈmɝdɚ/`. I do agree with DW that *union* is `/ˈjuːnjən/` with a `/jə/` diphthong.

Comment: Ah OK, so for you the vowel in "bear" merges with the vowel in "bay" and in "curer" you simply don't have a diphthong. It's just that in the UK, e.g. "curer would still be /kjʊəɹə/ with a diphthong for the first vowel. (Though whether most people nowadays deliberately diphthongise the vowel in "bear" is more questionable, I think.)

Comment: @Neil: to answer my own question, in the U.S. *bearer* and  *nearer* are less likely to have diphthongs than *bear* and *near* because of the NEARER-MIRROR and the *MERRY-MARY* mergers. I have /nɪɚ/ and /nɪɹɚ/, and /bɛɚ/ and /bɛɹɚ/, so the diphthong vanishes when a vowel follows it.

Comment: @NeilCoffey I just don’t read `/ʊə/` is a single syllable.  It has two, as in *lua* `/ˈlʊːə/`. I guess I might write that `/ˈlʊː.ə/` if I thought people would misunderstand me. And no, it is not homophonic with monosyllabic *lure* `/ˈl(j)ʊːɹ/`. I know of no  diphthongs in English that have neither a `/j/` nor a `/w/` in them, no matter how you may care to write those; other transcriptions are possible, as in `/eɪ/` for `/ej/`, and `/aʊ/` for `/aw/`. What English diphthong has no glide in it?

Comment: I don't pronounce `/eɪ/` (as in "same") as a diphthong.  I don't articulate a pure `/e/` or a pure `/ɪ/`, it's a constant vowel sound somewhere in between.  Sounds kinda weird pronounced by itself.

Comment: @Danielδ To me, *same* is just *say* with an *m* tacked on.

Comment: @DavidWallace Perhpas they don’t like *union* because they believe in falling diphthongs ( `/⊠j/, /⊠w/` ) only, not rising diphthong (`/j⊠/, /w⊠/`).  I imagine that people who don’t believe in rising diphthongs necessarily also disbelieve in triphthongs. Traditions of analysis very; for examples, Spanish is considered to have [both rising and falling diphthongs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_phonology#Diphthongs_and_triphthongs), and written in the most straightforward possible way, too.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was thinking phonetically, and in my California dialect the diphthong in price/mice/flight is different than my/high, but either way, phonemically or phonetically, there are certainly more than 2 diphthongs in every single dialect of English, it seems. And we Californians probably have (phonetically) among the fewest of the dialects of English.

Comment: @Daniel δ I'm surprised you don't pronounce a diphthong in "same". Your profile says your from Pennsylvania. I would have guessed you might be from Scotland or Ireland. I have a friend from Lancaster and his pronunciation doesn't differ significantly from mine. I have to wonder if you're just not hearing the diphthong, as a lot of Americans have a hard time with perceiving diphthongs at all (including the person I describe in my question, actually, who didn't hear the letter "i" as a diphthong).

Comment: @ButtleButkus  Interesting.  I'm pretty sure about the diphthong - once when I compiled a list of all the basic vowel sounds, the following were in my list - ă, ĕ, ĭ, ŏ, ŭ, ū, w, y (ē), aw, oo (as in *put*), ā, ō (not counting *r* and *l* which I'm still not sure of - thinking of words like *parlor*).  Ī is always a diphthong (ŏ transposing to ē), ē is always a non-diphthong, but ā, ō, and ū can all be non-diphthongs *or* diphthongs, depending on the word they're in.  Ā can be [ĕ - ē], ŏ can be [ŭ - w], and ū can be [ĭ - w].  It's interesting that ū (think *food*) is not considered a diphthong

Comment: @ButtleButkus *Say*, for instance, has the diphthong form of ā (ĕ - ē), but *same* doesn't.  *Toe* has the diphthong form of ō (ŭ - w), but *tone* doesn't.  *Do* has the diphthong form of ū (ĭ - w), but *doom* doesn't.  In my dialect, anyway.  Say them out loud, and listen carefully to the differences - *say - same, toe - tone, do - doom*.  Especially, try saying *same* as normal, except stop right before you say the *m* - it sounds very different from *say*.

Comment: @Daniel δ The constant vowel you describe is one I associate with German (e.g. "zehn" - the number 10). I don't think I've ever heard an American pronounce it. I think Scottish and Irish have more commonalities with Germanic languages and often use constant vowels where we use diphthongs. The same goes for toe/tone, and do/doom. There is no difference in the way I pronounce them except an added consonant. "Mail" is also exactly like "may" + "l" except perhaps an added schwa between.

Comment: Maybe I'm just weird, but I'm a Lancaster County native.

Comment: The idea that "goat" and "soul" might *ever* rhyme is quite surprising to me (BrE). Maybe if you're the king talking to Lord Poshington and you're having a particularly posh day it's just about imaginable that both would be [əʊ]. Is there some other part of the world where there is convergence in less ethereal registers?

Comment: @DanSheppard Did you perhaps mean *goal* and *soul*? *Goat* ends with /t/ but *soul* ends in /l/, so I don't know how those could ever rhyme, even if they share the vocalic part of their rime. It’s [a long topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/l/), but liquids like /r/ and /l/ lend themselves to things like L-vocalization and epenthetic-schwa insertion, and diphthongs smoothening into monophthongs. So you can find accents with mergers where you don’t otherwise expect them, like homophones in *tsar–sire–sigher* or rhymes in *mile–dial, fool–jewel*.

Comment: @tchrist sorry, I meant have the same vowels (ie assonance). I did mean "goat" and "soul". Per the first comment here, by user16269.

Comment: @DanSheppard There is no [əʊ] vowel in North American English. Except when alone at the end of a word, the *goat* vowel [ow] is often a plain monophthong [o] here the way it is in Scottish English, and most of us have the same vowel in *soul*. Certainly we all have the same abstract phoneme from the GOAT lexical set.  But some have pre-L breaking and produce ['sowəɫ] for *soul* instead, something which often sounds like it has two syllables for those of us who don’t have that accent. [You might enjoy this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtnlGH055TA).

Answer (score 8):

[Here](http://www.btinternet.com/~ted.power/folkchart.htm) you can find a chart of the 44 English phonemes.

[Here](http://www.btinternet.com/~ted.power/esl0105.html) you can find a chart of the eight diphthongs. Clicking on each one will get you a huge list of examples.

- **/eɪ/** as in *day, pay, say, lay*. ([Examples](http://www.btinternet.com/~ted.power/esl0105a.html))
- **/aɪ/** as in *sky, buy, cry, tie*. ([Examples](http://www.btinternet.com/~ted.power/esl0105b.html))
- **/ɔɪ/** as in *boy, toy, coy* or the first syllable of *soya*. ([Examples](http://www.btinternet.com/~ted.power/esl0105c.html))
- **/ɪə/** in *beer* (the drink), *pier*, *hear*. ([Examples](http://www.btinternet.com/~ted.power/esl0105d.html))
- **/eə/** as in *bear* (the animal), *pair* and *hair*. ([Examples](http://www.btinternet.com/~ted.power/esl0105e.html))
- **/ʊə/** as in *tour, poor* (talking posh!) or the first syllable of *tourist*. ([Examples](http://www.btinternet.com/~ted.power/esl0105f.html))
- **/əʊ/** as in *oh, no, so* or *phone*. ([Examples](http://www.btinternet.com/~ted.power/esl0105g.html))
- **/aʊ/** as in all the words of "How now brown cow!" ([Examples](http://www.btinternet.com/~ted.power/esl0105h.html))

[Help](http://www.paulmeier.com/ipa/diphthongs.html) on how to pronounce the different sounds.

Comment: Any comment from those who has voted negative ?

Comment: @speedyGonzales, there is nothing wrong with your answer. You gave a list of diphthongs commonly recognized by phoneticians for RP dialects. http://www.phonetics.ucla.edu/vowels/chapter3/bbcenglish.html

Comment: Could you please repair / replace the links you give, and add attributions, speedy? Also, please note that this one reference work isn't necessarily **_the_** final word on the actual situation, but rather one school of thought.

Answer (score 2):

In its current form, this question cannot be answered. **The number of diphthongs varies from dialect to dialect.**

For example, the word "four" in RP used to be pronounced as "foah", with a diphthong. Now the current RP form is "fo:" (long o). Or I say "sure" as "shuah", but there are many English speakers (in the UK) who say "sho:" (long o).

Comment: When a Southerner says  *four* or *sure*, I hear two syllables, not a diphthong. Similarly, since Suthun *some more* is homophonic with *Samoa*, it necessarily has three syllables, not two with a diphthong. And I do not think the phonemic set varies the way the phonetic set does.

Comment: I don't know much about US dialects, so I can't agree or disagree with you there. On the other hand, i apologize for saying a truism but the number of phonemes does vary, depending on your dialect.

Comment: I didn’t say all regional dialects had exactly the same set of phonemes. I said they didn’t vary the way the many phonetic realizations of those phonemes vary.

Comment: In that case I don't see how relevant it is to my answer.

Comment: I cannot possibly see how you think "foah" has a diphthong. Does "Boa" (as in *boa constrictor*) have two syllables or just one? Do you think "Samoa" has just two syllables or three? Yes, Suthun pronounces *boy*  disyllablically as though it were spelt "boa", but that’s not what I’m talking about.

Comment: Once again, it depends on your dialect and your definition of a diphthong, whether you recognize triphthongs etc. As for the words "boa" and "Samoa", three major pronunciation dictionaries (EPD17, LPD3, and ODP) say that there is "oh-ah" (and thus, LPD3 marks "boa" as disyllabic and "Samoa" trisyllabic), just like the way I pronounce them. I understand that you pronounce them differently, that's fine (see my answer above about the number of phonemes in different dialects). As for "foah", it's a well known fact - see http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/rphappened.htm (Merger of /ɔə/ and /ɔː/)

Comment: EPD17 argues for the monosyllabic "boa" and disyllabic "Samoa" because Roach, Hartman, and Setter recognize *triphthongs*.

Comment: This is the last I’ll say on the matter. People who replace an *r* with a schwa add a syllable to a word in the perceptions of speakers of most North American dialects, including General American and Canadian, let alone for someone from the Inland like me. They do not create a diphthong, but a new syllable. It’s part of why Suthuners get laughed at. RP speakers suffer the same abuse no doubt.  If you drop the *r* in *four* by making *fowah*, it sounds like two syllables to us, because we simply have no one-syllable "oa" diphthong in our phoneme set.

Comment: "because we simply have no one-syllable "oa" diphthong in our phoneme set." Good, finally you agree with me ("The number of diphthongs varies from dialect to dialect.")

Comment: No, I believe you are misanalysing "oa".  You’re perfectly welcome to say `/ˈmo.wə/` for *more* if that’s your dialect, but don’t expect me to call it a single syllable.

Comment: @tchrist, I don't expect you to apply rules of your dialect to someone else's dialect. That'll be absurd. In your dialect, there is no "uah" (unlike in some RP dialects) => no "uah" diphthong in your "sure" and "poor". However, it doesn't mean that  no one should have the uah diphthong in their dialect.

Comment: When people from Atlanta, Georgia say *sure*, I simply do not perceive their `/ʃʊːə/` (for my `/ʃʊːɹ/`) as monosyllabic. You might call the `/wa/` in *schwa* itself a rising diphthong, but I perceive the `/ʊː/` as the syllabic center of *sure*, and I do not recognize a schwa as a valid off-glide in a falling diphthong. Since schwa is not a glide like `/j/` or `/w/`, I hear it as a new syllable. And I am hardly alone. There are lots of jokes about this; look at all the “dialect spellings” that add “-uh” instead of an “r”.

Comment: @tchrist, "I do not recognize a schwa as a valid off-glide in a falling diphthong." Now your position is clear to me.

Comment: I already said that in my answer, that schwa is not a glide.

Comment: Sure, you can think that if you want. My point is that your analysis is one out of many.

Comment: I think the strict definition of a diphthong, triphthong, etc., essentially has to do with syllabicity. And so I think it is pretty useful to think of prosody. Roach, Hartman, and Jesus Christ can all claim that "boa" is monosyllabic, but I'm pretty sure Tennyson would count "boa" as having two syllables, the "bo" (with diphthong) and the "a". And "four" would depend on his pronunciation, with the version with the final schwa certainly having two syllables. The "owah" in "fowah" is not a diphthong, because no one perceives it as a single beat. I think tchrist is right on this one.

Comment: How do linguists determine the number of syllables in a word? It's based on the number of vowels and presence/absence of syllabic consonants. Your logic is circular. V+V is a not a diphthong under your proposal because they belong to different syllables. How do you determine that? Because you "perceive" it. As for "no one" perceives it as a single beat", maybe, if you're taking about linguistically naive people. Their opinion might be of some value, but not much. There are people who perceive Earth is flat, so should we believe them, too?

Answer (score 2):

There are ten diphthongs in Hollywood (NA) English where two sounds (a vowel followed so closely by a consonant they in effect make one vowel sound). The English Phonetic Alphabet (EPA) notation describes this clearly:

- long a /Ay/ – great, made, day, hey, rain, eight, chaos, suede, gauge …
- long e /Ey/ – meat, we, tree, peace, piece, quay, ski, naive, suite …
- long i /Iy/ – my, eye, aisle, knife, pie, find, I, choir …
- long o /Ow/ – go, know, boat, toe, goal, brooch, sew, bologna …
- long u /Uw/ – two, you, who, due, suit, new, cool, ewe, queue, lose …

You can probably see the pattern here – long vowels are long because there are two sounds in them.

Two more that could also be considered long for the same reason are:

- /Oy/ as in boy, noise, royal and buoy
- /Aw/ as in owl, house, drought

The three *r* vowels were a vowel plus *r* make a distinct new sound:

- /Ar/ – charcoal, park, heart, R
- /Er/ – purple, first, word, were, heard
- /Or/ – orange, four, more, war, door

Comment: Here is a link to [the English Phonetic Alphabet (EPA)](http://www.thompsonlanguagecenter.com/pdfs/english_phonetic_alphabet_article.pdf) (PDF) which seems to be what the poster is referring to. Apparently it is a teaching device for ESL.

Comment: The poster seems to have created the English Phonetic Alphabet. It might be a fairly accurate representation of her Southern California accent; it certainly has a number of traits consistent with English spoken in that area.

Answer (score 0):

First I learned diphthong from my Shorthand school, where we were taught only four diphthongs according to Sir Issac Pittman's Shorthand, quoting the definition,
"A union of two vowel sounds in one syllable.” (Prof. Sweet). They are, 
I, OW, OI, U, formed in the following way:

a + i = I -  like pipe, pike, etc.
a + ŏŏ = Ow - like couch, mouth, etc.
aw + I = Oi - like boy, joy, etc. 
i + oo = like due, few, etc.

Pittman's Shorthand also talks about triphones, a three vowel sound i.e. diphthong + any vowel, as used in: 
Diary, dialogue; Viola, towel; Power, boyish; Duet, strenuous, etc.

Comment: Hello, Ram. You can see that there are different and contradictory answers here; possibly, this is a convenient 'reduced set'. More comprehensive than OP's acquaintance's set of two, but not as comprehensive as others given.